# How to convert code into a mathematical formula for a LaTex document?

Tags: matlab, math, formula

Hi I want to know how I can convert MatLab code into a mathematical formula to present in LaTex document. I understand my code and how it works but I want to be able to present it as a mathematical formula.

Here are the pieces of code i want to convert to a mathematical formula

```
%averaging to remove common noise
for i=1:14
   datan(i,:)=data(i+2,:)-mean(data(3:16,:));
end


fmin  = 20;  % minimum passband frequency in Hz (High Gamma)
fmax  = 30;  % maximum passband frequency in Hz (High Gamma)
Rs    = 20; % stopband attenuation in dB
Rp    = 1;  % passband ripples in dB



% for High gamma band 
[order, Wn] = ellipord([fmin/(fs/2), fmax/(fs/2)], [(fmin-1)/(fs/2), (fmax+1)/(fs/2)], Rp, Rs);
[B,A] = ellip(order, Rp, Rs, [fmin/(fs/2), fmax/(fs/2)]); 

%filtering of entire data into High Gamma band
data_hgamma = filtfilt(B,A,datan');
```

So basically all this code is doing converting EDF data to matlab code, then averaging out the noise across the 14 channels from EEG headset, the it is specifying the frequency in order to apply the filter.

I know this is a bit of a random question but I would appreciate the help.

Comment: I am not aware of a converter for this... Especially I don't belive that it will be as readable as it should be. For example fmin should be f_min there I guess. And you generally have to write mathematical formulas defferent than MatLab code. So I would say write it clean in LaTeX.

Comment: where is the formula ?

Comment: @percusse I do not have the formula, I would like to convert some of my code into mathematical formulas.

Comment: Why don't you type it ? Without symbolic expressions you can't do it .